# ui-view with Meanjs 0.4.2

Tags: meanjs

I've been following a MEANJS.org-based video tutorial series which I have found to be one-of-a-kind on youtube.  However, the series was recorded at MEANJS 3.x and then ported to MEANJS 4.  However, it appears that MEANJS 4.2 has leveraged Angular Menu Service which works much differently than her demo.  This is making it impossible to follow how to add a UI Bootstrap Modal (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) which is fundamental to how the stack works with Bootstrap.

My questions are as follows:

1.) At version 4.2 of MEANJS do I have to use abstract ui-view templating? Or can I override that and just create states I want without using the master template ui view?

```
function routeConfig($stateProvider) {
.state('customers', {
abstract: true,
url: '/customers',
template: '<ui-view/>'
})
```

2.) How do I add modals with the Angular UI Bootstrap?  I have tried every which way, and am completely flummoxed.

3.) Are there any good resources that go into the architecture of MEANJS 0.4.2 that I am missing?  Most all the resources that have been recorded are using the earlier version which is quite different than the latest release.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The menu service is actually a part of MEANJS, it's in:

[/modules/core/client/services/menu.client.service.js](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/modules/core/client/services/menu.client.service.js)

Take a read of the source when you get a chance.

Recently the the ability to add parameters was added, however I don't see anything that should stop Angular UI Bootstrap from working.

I'm not sure which tutorial you're doing or if you're still working on this, however the best way to get AUIB to work if coming to it fresh is to just try to get the accordion on the page. It's the first example and should take you a couple minutes with cut and paste powers.

Make sure you understand how it works. Get a feel for how the controller is working with it. Then go back to the modal with clearer vision and boosted confidence.

Worst comes to worst clone the same version of MEANJS as the tutorial and then study the implementation until you understand it and can implement the same upgrades to current version.

You should be able to crack it - just keep at it!

Good luck!